# Validation not firing in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

```
<td>Type:

 </td>
  <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddltype" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem>---select---</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="Setter" Value="1">
       </asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Getter" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
```

For this dropdownlist, I put validation like this

```
var ddltype = document.getElementById('<%=ddltype.ClientID%>');
        var type = ddltype.options[ddltype.selectedValue].value;
        if (type == 0) {
            alert("Please Select setter/getter type.");
            return false;
        }
```

but it is not firing. How can I write this?

Comment: Why don't you use ASP.NET validators?

Comment: What is causing the javascript to fire? Is it in an onclick event? Why not use the build in ASP.NET Validation? `RangeValidator` with a minimum of 0 should do it?

Comment: your select choise has not any value. Make it;<asp:ListItem Text="---select---" Value="0"> then it ll work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really get familiar with ASP.NET validators. Javascript can be disabled.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddltype" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
     <asp:ListItem>---select---</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Setter" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Getter" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList><br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqType"  runat="server" 
    InitialValue="---select---" 
    ControlToValidate="ddltype"  
    ErrorMessage="Required: Please select a Type" 
    Display="Dynamic"
    CssClass="blah">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The `InitialValue` is important. Otherwise `---select---` would be a valid selection.

Note that i've also added  `AutoPostBack="true"` to the `DropDownList`, maybe you want to postback immediately as soon as the user has selected an item.

**Side-note**: use a `ValidationSummary` with   `ShowMessageBox="true"` and `EnableClientScript="true"` if you want to show the messages in a javascript alert.

Comment: The OP asked about javascript validation , But why you change him mind ?

Comment: ASP.NET validators also validate on clientside (if desired) but also serverside. It's also more readable and maintainable then fiddling around with (redundant) js- functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var ddltype = document.getElementById('<%=ddltype.ClientID%>').text;
 if (type == "---select---") {
        alert("Please Select setter/getter type.");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Also - way better is to use RequiredFieldValidator instead of writing custom js validation. RequiredFieldValidator will validate input also on server-side (ie. if your user has javascript disabled).

Comment: Yes, agree. But some demand client side validation like this.

Comment: Ramesh, I added ".value" to the ddltype assignment. The person who posted this missed out that.

Comment: @Aishvarya . The OP dropdown have't set value in first list item , So that time your code not get that , Please change value to text and change this way !!

Comment: hmm !! your welcome !! Now i explained that reason in my answer ! catch that ! happy coding !

Answer (score -1):

Try this way ! but you can use asp.net validation control .

> Any way ,my solution will validate two type ,for  the dropdown selected vale  or dropdown selected item

```
 function Validate()
    {
    var e = document.getElementById('<%=ddltype.ClientID%>');
    //if you need value to be compared then use
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    //if you need text to be compared then use
    var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    if(strUser==0) **//for text use if(strUser1=="---Select---")**
    {
    alert("Please Select setter/getter type.");
        return false;
    }
    }
```

The below code has change your some code and working good for me

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validation() {
            debugger;
            var e = document.getElementById('<%=ddltype.ClientID%>');
            var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            if (strUser1 == 0) {
                alert("Please Select setter/getter type.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="validation();" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddltype" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Setter" Value="1">
                        </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Getter" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and see this line

```
<asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
```

But you missed set value in that item , So it's get error, Now set value 0 in that line , and now your code working (See my sample code), Or you need to use `.text` and check the condition for

```
if(strUser1=="---Select---")
{
//alert
}
```